# React - MVC4 .Net - Blank page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reactjs

I want to use React in a MVC application. In this moment I'm trying to insert the jsx code in the main layout but it does not work.

I think that the problem is that jsx is not being transformed, because if I write the code in JavaScript code, everything works fine.

This is my code of the Layout.cshtml: 
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error! In the *React.Render* I was creating the  in lowercase () because Visual Studio sets it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your React code into a separate file (filename.jsx) and include it in the standard way (e.g. @Scripts.Render("filename.jsx")) back into the _layout

Comment: Hi Joe, I already try it and I receive this error: 'SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<''. I already fix the issue (it was the cammelCase of the class creation) but I would like to separate the code as you say.